# Wrong struct member values after pointer assignment

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

I'm trying to allocate memory for and initialize members of a struct.

In a function which takes a pointer to the struct and some other parameters (used in other members), I allocate the memory for the struct itself and its `nodes` member and initialize the other members. Printing the `size` and `len` members within the initialization function outputs the correct values, but testing them after the function outputs random garbage.

Why is this behavior occurring and what can I do to fix it?

Struct definitions:

```
struct node_t {
    int priority;
    void *data;
};

struct pqueue {
    int len,size,chunk_size;
    struct node_t *nodes;
};
```

Initialization function:

```
int alloc_pq(struct pqueue *q,int init_size,int chunk_size){
    // allocate for struct
    if((q=(struct pqueue*) malloc(sizeof(struct pqueue)))==NULL){
        perror("malloc");
        return -1;
    }

    // set initial sizes
    q->len=0;
    q->chunk_size=chunk_size;
    q->size=init_size;

    if(init_size>0){
        // allocate initial node memory (tried malloc here too)
        if((q->nodes=(struct node_t*) realloc(q->nodes,init_size*sizeof(struct node_t)))==NULL){
            perror("realloc");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    printf("%lu %d %d\n",sizeof(*q),q->size,q->len); // DEBUG
    return q->size;
}
```

In main function:

```
struct pqueue q;

...

alloc_pq(&q,n,0);
printf("%lu %d %d\n",sizeof(q),q.size,q.len); // DEBUG
```

Output (second last number is always > 32000, last is seemingly random):

```
24 67 0
24 32710 -2085759307
```

Comment: [should I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: `realloc` is definitely wrong when allocating memory for the nodes member. `malloc`  or `calloc` is correct.

Comment: You should use `malloc`, not `realloc`. You can only use `realloc` when the first argument is a pointer that was previously returned by `malloc/realloc`, or it's `NULL`. Neither of these is true in your function, you're passing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: also the value of `q` won't change after return, since it is passed by value.  You need to declare your function: `int alloc_pq(struct pqueue **q,int init_size,int chunk_size)`

Comment: @Barmar as I mentioned in the commenting I tried malloc and it made no difference to the issue. I thought I might as well try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do things is making no changes. You passed address and then overwrote it.

Any changes you make to `q` will be lost when that function ends. Solution would be to either take a pointer variable in `main()` and pass it's address.

```
struct pqueue* q;

...

alloc_pq(&q,n,0);
```

Change `alloc_pq` accordingly. Something like

```
int alloc_pq(struct pqueue **q,int init_size,int chunk_size){
    // allocate for struct
    if((*q=malloc(sizeof(struct pqueue)))==NULL){
        perror("malloc");
        return -1;
    }

    // set initial sizes
    (*q)->len=0;
    (*q)->chunk_size=chunk_size;
    (*q)->size=init_size;

    if(init_size>0){
        // allocate initial node memory (tried malloc here too)
        if(((*q)->nodes= realloc((*q)->nodes,init_size*sizeof(struct node_t)))==NULL){
            perror("realloc");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    printf("%lu %d %d\n",sizeof(*q),(*q)->size,(*q)->len); // DEBUG
    return (*q)->size;
}
```

Your use of `realloc` is wrong. Use a temporary vcariable to hold the result and check whether it returns NULL or not.

Casting the result of `malloc`,`realloc` is not needed. Free the memory allocated when you are done working with it. Check the return value of `malloc`,`realloc`.

```
struct node_t* temp= realloc((*q)->nodes,init_size*sizeof(struct node_t)));
if( temp == NULL ){
   perror("realloc");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
(*q)->nodes = temp;
```

Comment: Marked as accepted, but I'm casting `*alloc` family calls for compatibility with C++ compilers, as I may need that later.